# Why is the output "Value Error" showing up in my code?

Tags: python

I am new to python and have built a simple state tax calculator.
I have used one big function and if, elif, and else statements.

I have included inputs and formulas for each state.

```
def state_tax_calculator():
    s = input(("Hello! What state do you live in? "))
    n = int(input(("What was your income, in dollars, this year? ")))

    if s.title() == "Alabama":
        x = n*0.04
        y = n-(n*0.04)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Alaska":
        return "Lucky for you, there is no state tax in your state!"
    elif s.title() == "Arizona":
        x = n*0.056
        y = n-(n*0.056)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Arkansas":
        x = n*0.065
        y = n-(n*0.65)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "California":
        x = n*0.0725
        y = n-(n*0.0725)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Colorado":
        x = n*0.029
        y = n-(n*0.029)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Conneticut":
        x = n*0.0635
        y = n-(n*0.0635)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Delaware":
        x = n*0.0474
        y = n-(n*0.0474)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Florida":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Georgia":
        x = n*0.04
        y = n-(n*0.04)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Hawaii":
        x = n*0.04
        y = n-(n*0.04)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Idaho":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Illinois":
        x = n*0.0625
        y = n-(n*0.0625)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Indiana":
        x = n*0.07
        y = n-(n*0.07)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Iowa":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Kansas":
        x = n*0.065
        y = n-(n*0.065)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Kentucky":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Louisiana":
        x = n*0.0445
        y = n-(n*0.0445)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Maine":
        x = n*0.055
        y = n-(n*0.055)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Maryland":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Massachusetts":
        x = n*0.0625
        y = n-(n*0.0625)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Michigan":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Minnesota":
        x = n*0.0688
        y = n-(n*0.0688)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Mississippi":
        x = n*0.07
        y = n-(n*0.07)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Missouri":
        x = n*0.0423
        y = n-(n*0.0423)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Montana":
        x = n*0.0461
        y = n-(n*0.0461)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Nebraska":
        x = n*0.055
        y = n-(n*0.055)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Nevada":
        x = n*0.0685
        y = n-(n*0.0685)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "New Hampshire":
        return "Lucky for you, there is no state tax in your state!"
    elif s.title() == "New Jersey":
        x = n*0.0663
        y = n-(n*0.0663)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "New Mexico":
        x = n*0.0513
        y = n-(n*0.0513)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "New York":
        x = n*0.04
        y = n-(n*0.04)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "North Carolina":
        x = n*0.0475
        y = n-(n*0.0475)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "North Dakota":
        x = n*0.05
        y = n-(n*0.05)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Ohio":
        x = n*0.0575
        y = n-(n*0.0575)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Oklahoma":
        x = n*0.045
        y = n-(n*0.045)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Oregon":
        x = n*0.0725
        y = n-(n*0.0725)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Pennsylvania":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Rhode Island":
        x = n*0.07
        y = n+(n*0.07)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "South Carolina":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "South Dakota":
        x = n*0.045
        y = n-(n*0.045)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Tennessee":
        x = n*0.07
        y = n-(n*0.07)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Texas":
        x = n*0.0625
        y = n-(n*0.0625)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Utah":
        x = n*0.0595
        y = n-(n*0.0595)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Vermont":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Virginia":
        x = n*0.053
        y = n-(n*0.053)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Washington":
        x = n*0.065
        y = n-(n*0.065)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "West Virginia":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Wisconsin":
        x = n*0.05
        y = n-(n*0.05)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "Wyoming":
        x = n*0.04
        y = n-(n*0.04)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    elif s.title() == "District Of Columbia":
        x = n*0.06
        y = n-(n*0.06)
        return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}."
        return f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}."
    else:
        return input(("That is not a state, please enter a state: "))
```

I expect:
"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is _." and "Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is _."

However, I am either getting a ValueError saying "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '200,000' "
 or it is only returning the first statement above.

Thank you, 
Theo Tobel

Comment: That's a lot of code duplication. You should create a dictionary where the keys are states and the values are tax rates. Also, you don't seem to understand how `return` works.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to python and forgot that the return keyword ends the execution of a function. I will change the code for each state to:                     return f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}, which means that your income after tax is {y}."

Comment: I wouldn't bother changing the `return` statements. Try to refactor the code as I suggested. Create a dict like: `tax_rates = {"Alabama": 0.04, "Alaska": 0.056, ...}`, then you can calculate `x` and `y` on 2 lines, e.g. `x = n * tax_rates[s]`.

Comment: @krisz Yes, that is a much better idea! I knew there was a better way to do it after all the copy and pasting...  :P

Answer (score 1):

> "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '200,000' "

This means your input statement cannot be converted to an integer. This is because you have a comma in 200,000. Change it to 200000

Comment: Or if you (end-user) wanted to do that for clarity, you could try typing in `200_000` which is valid Python. It was added in Python 3.6 for this purpose :)

Comment: Thank you Anna. There is one more problem; the code returns the first return statement, the state tax cost, but not the statement that says the person's income after the tax is applied. Is there an error in the code that stops the second statement from returning?

Comment: You can only return once. It's like a strict teacher asking for an answer and only accepts a single answer. She'll ignore everything else that you say other than the first answer you gave. Same goes for the `return` statement. (Whoops, looks like krisz already got your back :)

Comment: @theotobel sorry I did not look much at your code besides the traceback you provided, but yes you cannot write functions like the way you did. You can only have one return statement in a function, it will stop after the first. You should do return (f"Your state tax cost, in dollars, is {x}.", f"Your income after the state tax, in dollars, is {y}.")

Comment: @GeeTransit that was a wonderful metaphor, A++

Comment: Thanks :) It did make me feel a lil uneasy about going back to school soon :P

Comment: @GeeTransit Thanks for the help (and the metaphor). Only 2 more weeks until school for me :(

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma in `200,000` so it cannot be converted to an int. Remove the comma. You can also do `200_000` in Python if you want it to be separated for readability.